# Derivative of a function defined by an integral with $e^{-t^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm facing a bit of a tricky question and I can't figure out how to get to the correct answer. We have to find the derivative of the following functions:

(1) $F(x) = \int^{x}_{3} e^{-t^{2}} dt$

(2) $G(x) = x^{2} . \int^{5x}_{-4} e^{-t^{2}} dt$

(3) $H(x) = \int^{x^3}_{x^2} e^{-t^{2}} dt$

As I have discovered, $e^{-t^{2}}$ has no closed form and is just defined in the error function. I have got the answer to the first question using the fundamental theorem of calculus, getting an answer of $e^{-x^{2}}$ however I can't get the correct answer for the other two. Could someone help me and explain how to get the answers to (2) and (3)? I have seen the answers on Wolfram Alpha and there appears to be some sort of chaining within the integral which I cannot understand.

Thanks! Helen

Comment: Hint: For the second one, use the product rule and then FTC.  You may also want to do a substitution where $t=5u$.  For the third one.  Break your integral into $\int_0^{x^3}-\int_0^{x^2}$

Comment: What is "FTC"? The product rule is fine, I know how to do that, but I don't know how to find the integral because the bound is $5x$ and not $x$. What do I do here, as the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus only gives me $G(5x) - G(-4)$ and not $G(x)$ as required.

Comment: FTC is the **F**undamental **T**heorem of **C**alculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [Fundamental Theorem of calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpVkVTAlfMI)
For instance

$(1)$ $F'(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

$(2)$ Use the product Rule for derivatives and the chain rule.

$$G'(x) = 2x \int_{-4}^{5x} e^{-t} dt + x^2 \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{-4}^{5x} e^{-t} dt\bigg)$$

(3) Remember that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = \int_{a}^{c} f(t) dt + \int_{c}^b f(t) dt$$

Comment: If you see in my post I said I have ALREADY used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve the first one. It is (2) and (3) I am having trouble with, as I said.

Comment: The product rule is not an issue, it is the integral that is tricky, as the bound is $5x$ and not $x$

Comment: Make use of the Chain Rule.

Comment: How do I use the chain rule with an integral?

Comment: The same way you'd use with any other function. In this case you function on $(2)$ is $H(x) = \int_{-4}^{5x} e^{-t} dt$. So it would be $H'(f(x)) = H'(f(x)) f'(x) $, where in this case $f(x) = 5x$.

Comment: It finally clicked with me, I see what you mean now! Thanks!

Comment: That's great!! I'm sure you're not going to forget it!! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

2) $$G(x) = x^{2} . \int^{5x}_{-4} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$
First use the product rule of differentiation. In this calculation the derivative of $$\int^{5x}_{-4} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$ will appear. The derivative of a function $h(ax)$ with $a$ a constant is $ah'(ax)$. Take $a = 5$ and use this to get the derivative of the integral.

3) Hint: $$F(x) = \int^{{x}^3}_{{x}^{2}} e^{-t^{2}} dt = \int^{{x}^3}_{0} e^{-t^{2}} dt+\int^{0}_{{x}^{2}} e^{-t^{2}} dt = \int^{{x}^3}_{0} e^{-t^{2}} dt-\int^{{x}^{2}}_{0} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$

Answer (score 0):

(1) $F(x)=\int_3^x{e^{-t^2}dt}$

Then,applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$

(2) $G(x)=x^2\cdot\int_{-4}^{5x}e^{-t^2}=uv$

$u'=2x$

Applying the chain rule,  $v'=5e^{-{(5x)}^2}$

Applying the product rule, $G'(x)=uv'+vu'=5x^2e^{-(5x)^2}+2x\int_{-4}^{5x}{e^{-{t}^2}}$

(3) $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x^3}{e^{-t^2}}-\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}$

Applying the chain rule and the addition rule

$F'(x)=3x^2e^{-x^6}-2xe^{-x^4}$

I hope I have not made any mistake, but this is what I know.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ and $v$ are functions in $x$ and $$F(x) = \int^{v}_{u} f(t) dt$$ , then
$$F'(x)=v'f(v)-u'f(u)$$